# SQL Custom column based on the values in the column

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where I need to show specific status value in new column

logic:

> for the ID, if any status is converted, show converted
>   if all status is closed for the ID only then show closed 
>   else show open

i am having trouble in looking in the column to find if all are closed for specific ID or if any is converted, please help how to handle it :

Data :

```
ID  SUBID  Status 
1    5     new
1    6     closed
1    7     wip
2    22    Converted
2    25    Closed
3    11    closed
3    44    closed
```

output i want to get

```
ID  status
1    open
2    Converted
3    Closed
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a matter of conditions and aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when status = 'converted' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'converted'
             when min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'closed'
             then 'closed'
             else 'open'
         end)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Love you sir, thanks for your quick help. darn i was in an impression that min, max functions can not be used with string :(